# UIButton interaction is not smooth when used in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I Have a UICollectionViewCell in which I have added UIButton. Normally button action gets called but some times it does not. When same button I add in a viewcontroller the interaction is very smooth. Even a gentle tap trigger the action. 
Below is the code for button :

```
 func makeTapButton(for superView: UIView) -> UIButton {
      let offSetValue = 15
      let button = UIButton()
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
      superView.addSubview(button)
      button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
         make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(-offSetValue)
         make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(offSetValue)
         make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(-offSetValue)
         make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(offSetValue)
     }
     return button
 }

   func setupCustomView() {
     self.addSubview(containerStackView)
     containerStackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(self)
        make.leading.equalTo(self)
        make.trailing.equalTo(self)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self)
    }

    containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(commentStack)
    containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(retweetStack)
    containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(likeStack)
    commentStack.addArrangedSubview(commentImageView)
    commentStack.addArrangedSubview(commentsCountLabel)
    retweetStack.addArrangedSubview(retweetImageView)
    retweetStack.addArrangedSubview(retweetCountLabel)
    likeStack.addArrangedSubview(likeImageView)
    likeStack.addArrangedSubview(likesCountLabel)

    likeButton = makeTapButton(for: likeStack)
    commentButton = makeTapButton(for: commentStack)
    retweetButton = makeTapButton(for: retweetStack)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below mentioned code when using UIbutton placed in collectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        cell.btnName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnSelClk), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.binSel.tag = collectionView.tag
        cell.binSel.accessibilityValue = String(indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }

@objc func btnSelClk(sender:UIButton) {
        selectAry[sender.tag] = sender.accessibilityValue!
         // your button action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining your buttons in UICollectionViewCell class and your functions in UIViewController class being less laggy because they are reused;

```
import UIKit

class YourCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var yourBtn: UIButton!

var yourButtonAction: (() -> ())?


 @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UISlider) {

        yourButtonAction()
    }

}
```

then in your ViewController where you call your cell;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCell", for: indexPath) as! YourCell

cell.yourBtn = {[unowned self] in
      // call your functions here, I hope this will be less laggy 
     print("button pressed")
  }


}
```